# Changed the UEFI motherboard on a dell laptop, now it says no OS detected

Tags: boot, uefi, motherboard

My laptop was running the latest Ubuntu, because of a minor issue, the motherboard was replaced. The new motherboard has the same specifications as old. But after replacing, the OS is not detected.

- Is there some setting in BIOS which can fix the issue or should I
  really re-install Ubuntu?
- If I re-install Ubuntu, will I lose the
  data?

Help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Change boot device in bios. Is it UEFI?

Comment: Thank you, but can you let me know to which boot device needs to be selected

Comment: The device where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: its in the hard disk

Comment: Yes, the system is set to UEFI

Comment: Boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB and post a link to gparted screenshot. I will give you a guide how to fix it.

Comment: Here s the screenshot http://i.share.pho.to/a3838b9b_c.png

Comment: It is too small and not full.

Comment: http://pho.to/9glXA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path to Ubuntu efi loader should be added to your motherboard UEFI.

Boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB and run in terminal:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -l "\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI" -L ubuntu
```

Then reboot normally. You will get a boot option "ubuntu".

**If your EFI partition is not the default /dev/sda1**, then the command will look this way:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -l "\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI" -L ubuntu -d /dev/sdX -p N
```

where `/dev/sdX` is the disk and `N` is the partition number. If your EFI partition is /dev/sdb2, then it will look as `-d /dev/sdb -p 2`.

Comment: Thank you, that did bring up the ubuntu option in bios. Even after selecting that, the screen says no boot device found

Comment: all I see in boot priority order are, ubuntu, onboard nic-ipv4, onboard nic-ipv6. So, no HDD right?

Comment: I made a mistake. There should be quotes. Run `sudo efibootmgr -Bb 0000` and run the updated command. @Reva Without qoutes it does not work for me too.

Comment: You are the man. The one with quotes worked. I guess you need to update the other version of the command as well.

Comment: *"The path to Ubuntu efi loader should be added to your motherboard UEFI."* are you sure it's saved "on the motherboard"? It seems it's saved in the EFI partition, but not saved on the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Following Pilot6's [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/668524/1151435), I was able to solve my problem with a few changes. My system was running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server when this strange issue occurred due to a possible power loss with the Intel® Server Board S2600WF. I tried to solve it with a live Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but it did not have the command `efibootmgr` or internet connectivity, so I couldn't install the software. I finally decided to boot with [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and run it. Running the command:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -l "\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI" -L ubuntu
```

and restarting the system I was able to see Ubuntu in the boot options. Operation was back to normal afterwards.