# Computer not booting after attempt to install CD/DVD Drive

Tags: 16.04, cd-drive

I tried to install the LG Multi DVD Writer (model : GH24NSD1) to my (up until now perfectly working) desktop. I turned my computer off, unplugged the PSU, plugged the DVD drive to the power supply and motherboard, plugged back in the PSU and tried booting. At first I obtained no video output (i.e. monitor was getting no signal) and I obtained two short beeps from the motherboard.

I tried unplugging the DVD drive to check if I did something wrong. Now it's stuck in a reboot loop and I do get signal to the monitor but it only gives it a black screen (from the boot until the next reboot, the only signal the monitor gets is a black screen ; no keyboard key allows me to access any menu whatsoever), whether the DVD drive is plugged in or not. It takes about 15-30 seconds between the boot and the autoreboot. The only difference when the DVD drive is plugged in is that I get those two beeps but otherwise the reboot loop is happening.

Here are my specs :

- CPU -  i7 6700k LGA1151
- GPU - NVidia GTX 970
- Motherboard - z170a Gigabyte
- RAM - 2× DDR4 8Gb sticks for 16Gb total
- Power supply - Thermaltake Paris 650W 80 Plus Gold
- SSD : 500GB Samsung EVO

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as my OS. Because of an unrelated problem I had before, I am booting with the "quiet splash" option removed.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Two Beeps is a [Beep-Code](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005473.html) from your BIOS signaling a specific hardware problem. I'm sorry, this isn't about Ubuntu and thus your question will most probably be closed as "Off-topic"

Comment: My guess is that you dislodged / disconnected something - make sure the graphics card and memory are firmly seated, and everything is properly connected. Does the disk activity light come on when booting ?

Comment: UEFI NVRAM loses its memory of what to boot when drive is unplugged. Did you move drives around in SATA port order? And best to have drives in SATA port order, or SSD as SATA0, and DVD last in ports used. If still issues post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred : Thanks to you, I looked for "SATA0" on my motherboard and finally found that SATA0. As my computer previously worked the SSD was plugged in SATA2 because I could see the SATA2-3 slots but not the 0-1-4-5, which are somehow less visible. I plugged in the SSD in the SATA0 slot alone and still had the same booting problem. I tried plugging SSD on SATA0 and DVD drive in SATA1 and got the same problem + the two beeps. Similarly if I plugged the DVD drive in SATA5 instead (I didn't know if by "last" you meant 1 or 5 since I have SATA0, SATA1, ..., SATA5 ports.)

Comment: Full cold boot should find hard drive's ESP - efi system partition and add entries back. But if you have fast boot in UEFI (different than Windows fast start) it skips checking for new or different hardware. You can run Boot-Repair and full uninstall/reinstall of grub to add entry to UEFI or use efibootmgr to add boot entry.

Comment: @oldfred : Sadly I don't understand what you said. I only have Ubuntu as an OS on my computer, it never had anything else than Ubuntu 16.04 (it's a few weeks old, built from parts I bought online). If I run Boot-Repair do I just have to dumbly ask to re-install grub or are there more specifics I will have to input?

Comment: Boot-Repair's advanced mode has an uninstall/reinstall grub option. As part of that, it will reinstall an UEFI boot entry. Be sure to be in UEFI mode, otherwise it may install a BIOS boot version of grub which you do not want. You can just run efibootmgr to add entry: http://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected

Comment: @oldfred : What do I do if I can't run boot-repair because I can't run my computer from the USB drive? (When the USB drive is plugged in, I still get the same issue.)

Comment: Did you leave fast start up on in UEFI? then full cold boot, or power off, remove battery, if laptop and hold power switch for 10 sec to drain power. If that does not work, you have to remove coin battery or jumper pins on motherboard for full reset. But then have to change UEFI settings again as everything is back to defaults. I documented all my UEFI changes so when updating UEFI, I know what to reset.

Comment: The computer was running fine before this problem happened. Since then I have not been able to access any kind of menu whatsoever. I think the technical term (which I learn through googling because of this) is that my computer won't POST.