# Multiboot missing after cloning SSD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have a Windows/Ubuntu installation that was working fine. When my laptop booted I would get a solid purple screen with white letters offering me a choice of which OS I wanted to boot.

Yesterday I receive an RMA replacement for my SSD and had to clone the existing SSD. After cloning to the new RMA SSD and installing it my laptop boots straight into Windows 10.

I seem to recall there being a Linux utility that would repair the multiboot select, but I can't recall that name of it or how to use it.

This same thing happened when I cloned my original HDD to SSD. I asked the question here and the answer worked great - easy! But I don't see that question listed in my profile now.

**Details:**

```
Windows 10
Ubuntu v15.10
Sandisk SSD Extreme Pro 960gb
```

Here is a screenshot of `fdisk -l`

[image]

I don't have any reason to believe I have a corrupted partition or unbootable Ubuntu. I think it's just the same issue I had the first time and running a Linux utility recommended here fixed it perfectly.

Btw, I believe I use Grub. It's possible I was just told to reinstall Grub? For some reason my memory is failing me on this. Maybe it was just extremely simple...

After booting from a Live CD and opening a terminal window I try to run `/sudo apt-get-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` I get a not found error on apt-get-repository - it is not in /sbin nor anywhere I've looked so I'm unable to install Boot-Repair as some articles suggest.

Can anyone point me to the Linux/Ubuntu utility I might have used previously or what procedure will restore Grub 'safely'?

Comment: When you disconnect a drive UEFI NVRAM forgets all of its settings. You may get it to find then with several full cold boots, not reboots. If laptop remove battery & hold power switch for 10 sec to drain power. If not use Boot-Repair to totally reinstall grub in advanced options which should create new UEFI entry. Or use efibootmgr to add entry: http://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected

Comment: Been reading that Boot-Repair should do it, but `sudo apt-get-repository ...` returns not found. How do I get Boot-Repair? And yes, this is a laptop.

Comment: Btw, I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed on the SSD. It looks like the Live CD I have is Ubuntu 15.04. I don't know if that makes any difference. I clicked Ubuntu Software Center on the desktop and see that Grub can be installed from there, but I don't see that procedure documented anywhere so I didn't install it. Boot-Repair is not found in Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Must have read an answer with a bad instruction. `apt-get-repository` must be `add-apt-repository` - retrying.

Comment: If live installer is 15.04, I do not think Boot-Repair will work. It expects and has in its ppa only the current versions of Ubuntu. For a while Boot-Repair did not have current versions and we had to use work arounds by changing version. Just use current versions now, not as shown: Workaround. Change ppa from trusty to saucy.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2216051&p=12986335#post12986335