# Cloning Ubuntu 16 to boot in same model hardware

Tags: boot, uefi, thinkpad

I installed Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS on a fresh disk in an IBM ThinkPad x140E - not as dual boot, just the only OS. I do not need dual boot.

Boot mode is: Secure Boot Off and UEFI boot only.

We have FIVE of these same exact model ThinkPads and I wanted to have a clone of this setup running in another one.

I used Clonezilla to copy the disk and either disk will boot in the original ThinkPad with no problems.

I took one of the disks to a second ThinkPad but neither disk will boot in that system.

No matter how I set the BIOS I cannot get to anything but a BIOS select boot device screen - none of which will boot.

I suspect this is related to UEFI but I have no idea what to do to get the second system booted.

Comment: I notice that the original system that boots either disk is at firmware level 2.04 but the one that won't boot is at 2.12.

Does UEFI care? I bet it does.

Comment: Clonezilla, does not update UEFI with new entries for UEFI boot. You probably can just use efibootmgr to add correct entries, but easier to just use Boot-Repair to run a full uninstall/reinstall of grub-efi-amd64 and it will update UEFI with correct entries.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Using efibootmgr: http://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected Usually best to have UEFI at newest available from vendor.