# Grub cannot load ubuntu after setting up dual boot on two different disks

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100.
Previously I used to have a dual boot on a single built-in HDD and everything was perfect. For christmas I got a SSD and I wanted to set up a new dual boot: Windows 10 on the HDD and Ubuntu on the SSD.
Firstly I uninstalled Ubuntu from the HDD, I then installed Ubuntu on the SSD with a pendrive, but there is no way I can make Ubuntu boot.
When I turn on my PC, some error-messages show up, but they immediately disappear so that I can't read them. Then I end up in the grub command-line interface.
There I can do two different things:

- I can type 'exit' and then hit enter, now I can choose between different boot options so that I can load Windows 10 like nothing has happened.
- Otherwise I can type 'ls' and some tuples show up, like:    ... and finally "error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd1'" (there are other two similar errors"

Can someone help me? I found different questions here about dual boot, but everytime people had trouble loading windows, or the mistake was the different OS installation (UEFI coexisting with BIOS). The latter doesn't seem to be my case because when I used to have dual boot on the same HDD, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Are you able to boot into Ubuntu at all? If so what happens when you run these commands `sudo update-grub` and
`sudo os-prober`

Comment: @oldfred Here is the uploaded bbot-info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26280589/
I can't boot into Ubuntu, I just see the command-line interface, the only OS I can boot into is Windows, by selecting it's boot option

Comment: it looks like you created a duplicate ESP - efi system partition on sda7. Your UEFI entry for Ubuntu uses the PARTUUID (GUID) from that partition. Windows uses the GUID from sda1. Compare output from blkid and efibootmgr -v as in report. You should delete current ubuntu entry in UEFI and add a new one. See `man efibootmgr` & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289179&p=13331743#post13331743 and then new one: `sudo efibootmgr -c -l "\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI" -L ubuntu` https://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected

Comment: @oldfred 
Do I have to use a live session of Ubuntu, right? I tried with sudo efibootmgr -b xxxx -B (where xxxx is the entry number i want to delete) but as I reboot the PC, the entry is still there. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you do `sudo efibootmgr -v` before & after does the entry you want to delete then removed?

Comment: @oldfred no way, the entry is still in my UEFI boot options whenI turn on my PC again. Of course when i type `sudo efibootmgr -v` again I see the entry has been removed, but it seems that after a reboot the entry spawns again
Do I have to save changes in any way? After running those commands I simply shut down my PC

Comment: Some systems find the .efi boot files in the ESP - efi system partition,particularly default Windows or fallback in /EFI/Boot. I would then remove any incorrect entries/folders in /EFI/*. You typically want /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (and its backup that Boot-Repair makes), files in /EFI/ubuntu and files in /EFI/Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70989/discussion-between-federico-di-cesare-and-oldfred).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how far you are with configuring either operating system. But its best to install windows THEN Ubuntu. This allows grub to configure the boot loader accordingly for both OS.

My process usually is:

1) Install Windows

2) Enter disk management to shrink partition volume (For you this step is not necessary)

3) Enter Linux USB and install

4) Select your partition(drive for you) and install

Ideally this will allow GRUB to see the windows install and configure the Boot loader accordingly.

Comment: That's the sequence i followed. Once there was only windows, then I shrinked it's partition in order to have a working dual boot with ubuntu. It worked perfectly and I used both OSs for months. Now I uninstalled only linux and extended the windows partition. Then I installed Ubuntu on the other drive (a new one)