# Install grub on local hard disk

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu

I have a hard drive which contains my previous installation of Ubuntu as my laptop got damaged (I am currently using it as an external hard drive). Now I have managed to copy my Ubuntu installation from the externsl drive to my local hard drive on my new laptop but I can only boot into it only when the external drive is connected (The grub menu only appears when it is).

Once I disconnect the drive and restart the laptop, I hñget the grub command screen. How can I install grub on my local disk so I can boot without the use of the drive?

Comment: Older BIOS or newer UEFI? May be as simple as `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`. But may be best to review exact configuration. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: It's UEFI, not BIOS.

Comment: Do you have an ESP - efi system partition on sda? You probably need to use efibootmgr to add an Ubuntu entry to UEFI menu, but must have boot files in the /EFI/ubuntu folder in the ESP. https://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected and/or: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789