# efibootmgr does not display anything

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, refind

I had issues installing Ubuntu on a HP laptop. The problem was that the installation stops at installing grub2. I tried it on different Ubuntu versions but it gives me the same error.

I eventually worked around it by following the solution in this [forum post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=254975) .
I was able to install ubuntu 18.10 without grub and put the refind files inside the EFI directory. But i can't run this command:

```
efibootmgr -c -l \\EFI\\refind\\refind_x64.efi -L rEFInd
```

it is stuck there without outputting anything.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: You need sudo. And that command assumes ESP is sda1. If not sda1 or NVMe, you must specify correct drive & partition with additional parameters. See `man efibootmgr`  Not a rEFInd example but shows drive/partition: https://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected

Comment: Yes i am executing it with sudo. i've also tried the -disk option to no avail. It just keeps running without outputting anything.

Comment: What model HP? Have you updated UEFI from HP. HP used to not be very good, but some have reported that at least some models are now better when UEFI is updated.

Comment: I worked around the problem in a somewhat nasty way. For now it's ok but if the problem represent itself I will update UEFI. Thank you.