# Add BIOS boot menu entry to grub

Tags: grub2

My laptop lists bootable devices when the ESC key is pressed during power on.

[image]

I've already added an entry to BIOS setup in grub2. Similarly, is it possible to add an entry to the BIOS [boot menu](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/boot_menu.htm)?

Comment: It looks like you have an UEFI system. You cannot add BIOS boot to UEFI grub. Once you start booting in one mode or the other you cannot change. So grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode, Best to have all systems UEFI on UEFI hardware. But if booting old drive, you can select it from your menu above. you can add UEFI boot entries with efibootmgr. See  `man efibootmgr`, some examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected

Comment: You know you can press `F2` or similar key during boot up to enter BIOS setup and skip Grub and all the other stuff right?